# Doctrine2 migrations migrate down and migrate from browser and not command line

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using Doctrine2 migrations. I need some answers about my doubt, I canno find a good solution in documentations

I use:

```
  doctrine migrations:diff // generate migrations files
  doctrine migrations:migrate // migrates up to new version
```

1. How Can I migrate down? specifying the previous version did not work ( nothing to update it says f.e. doctrine migrations:migrate Version20120211163332 it says

   ```
   Migrating up to Version20120211163332 from 20120309112058

   [Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\MigrationException]  
   Could not find any migrations to execute.
   ```

   But it's not up it should be down! you can see also on versions in response
2. If I have to make some DB update, is it possible to add some SQL Queries in additions ( alter some datas related to other) ?  I have not tried still since the down is not working :((
3. Is there any way to use the migrate command in a browser nutshell ? I have sw in a shared  hosting without console access so I need this feature, instead of copying queries one by one :D in phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I saw this doc on Symfony's website : http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html#usage

There is `doctrine:migrations:execute` that allows you to execute a single migration version up or down manually... but never tried, sorry.

Hope this helps !

Keep us posted.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I kept your as an accepted answer, at least you have tried!!

Yes I have read the documentation ( also before write the question ) . If going up it's no problem, but down is a nightmare.

Also keep note that if you are working in team with subversioning it's best to IGNORE the migration folder, and make the migrate command every time a refresh of the working copy is made

Comment: use "doctrine:migrations:latest" to get the latest version, before the "execute --down" command. Makes things a little easier.

Answer (score 119):

You can optionally manually specify the version you wish to migrate to:

```
 php doctrine.php migrations:migrate YYYYMMDDHHMMSS
```

or execute a migration up/down

```
php doctrine.php migrations:execute YYYYMMDDHHMMSS  --down
php doctrine.php migrations:execute YYYYMMDDHHMMSS  --up
```

You can found YYYYMMDDHHMMSS using:

```
php doctrine.php migrations:status
>> Current Version:           2012-12-20 23:38:47 (20121220233847)
>> Latest Version:            2012-12-20 23:38:47 (20121220233847)
```

Comment: This is spot on. Its hardly difficult as others suggest, the hardest thing is copying the date stamp out of the filename!

For those using symfony, simply call app/console doctrine:migrations:execute YYYYMMDDHHMMSS  --down

Comment: Furthermore you can pass entity manager(em) parameter if your doctrine.yaml has multiple ems setup. 
`php bin/console doctrine:migrations:execute 20180409085702 --down --em=customer`.

Comment: execute with specific number down did not migrate latest versiosn down. I was expecting that when you give the version to which to migrate, it will first run down latest migration, then second latest, and so on.

Comment: Thank you so much, the idiotic official documentation doesn't mention rollbacks, even in Symfony 4 in 2019... WTF

Comment: Starting with 3.0+ you need to write FQCN, not the number. Docs: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-migrations/en/3.0/reference/managing-migrations.html#executing-single-migrations

Answer (score 45):

If you want to migrate 1 step down, you can use this syntax:

```
./doctrine migrations:migrate prev
```

To go to the first migration:

```
./doctrine migrations:migrate first
```

To go to the next migration:

```
./doctrine migrations:migrate next
```

Source: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-migrations/en/1.8/reference/managing_migrations.html#managing-migrations

Comment: When I used prev, it went 2 steps backward.

Comment: this was the solution that worked for me on symfony 5.3 . The official docs really need to add this

Answer (score 10):

Here is how you can run migrations from browser:

**composer.json**

```
{
    "require": {
        "doctrine/dbal": "*",
        "doctrine/migrations": "dev-master"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {"": "src/"}
    }
}
```

**src/Acme/Migrations/Version1.php**

```
<?php # src/Acme/Migrations/Version1.php
namespace Acme\Migrations;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\AbstractMigration;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema;

/**
 * Class Version1
 *
 * Notice that file and class names MUST be Version*.php
 *
 * @package Acme\Migrations
 */
class Version1 extends AbstractMigration
{
    public function up(Schema $schema)
    {
        $users = $schema->createTable('users');
        $users->addColumn('id', 'integer', array('unsigned' => true, 'autoincrement' => true));
        $users->addColumn('username', 'string', array('length' => 128));
        $users->addColumn('password', 'string', array('length' => 128));
        $users->setPrimaryKey(array('id'));

        // You can also add any queries
        // $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE addresses (id INT NOT NULL, street VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) ENGINE = InnoDB');
    }

    public function down(Schema $schema)
    {
        $schema->dropTable('users');

        //$this->addSql('DROP TABLE addresses');
    }

    // Use this functions to prepare your migrations
    //public function preUp(Schema $schema) {}
    //public function postUp(Schema $schema) {}
    //public function preDown(Schema $schema) {}
    //public function postDown(Schema $schema) {}
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php # index.php
use Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\Configuration\Configuration;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\Migration;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\OutputWriter;

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$nl = PHP_SAPI == 'cli' ? PHP_EOL : '<br>'; // Optional will be used for output

$to = null; // Optional integer - migrate to version, if null - will migrate to latest available version
#region Optional get argument
$index = PHP_SAPI == 'cli' ? 1 : 'to';
$arguments = PHP_SAPI == 'cli' ? $argv : $_REQUEST;
$to = isset($arguments[$index]) && filter_var($arguments[$index], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) ? intval($arguments[$index]) : null;
#endregion

#region Doctrine Connection
// Silex: $app['db']
// Symfony controller: $this->get('database_connection')
$db = DriverManager::getConnection(array(
    'dbname' => 'doctine_migrations',
    'user' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'driverOptions' => array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'
    )
));
#endregion

#region Config
$config = new Configuration($db /*, new OutputWriter(function ($message) { echo $message . PHP_EOL; })*/); // OutputWriter is optional and by default do nothing, accepts closure for writing logs

//$config->setName('My Migrations'); // Optional name for your migrations
$config->setMigrationsTableName('version'); // Table name that will store migrations log (will be created automatically, default name is: doctrine_migration_versions)
$config->setMigrationsNamespace('Acme\\Migrations'); // Namespace of your migration classes, do not forget escape slashes, do not add last slash
$config->setMigrationsDirectory('src/Acme/Migrations'); // Directory where your migrations are located
$config->registerMigrationsFromDirectory($config->getMigrationsDirectory()); // Load your migrations
#endregion

$migration = new Migration($config); // Create Migration based on provided configuration

$versions = $migration->getSql($to); // Retrieve SQL queries that should be run to migrate you schema to $to version, if $to == null - schema will be migrated to latest version

#region Some dummy output
foreach ($versions as $version => $queries) {
    echo 'VERSION: ' . $version . $nl;
    echo '----------------------------------------------' . $nl . $nl;

    foreach ($queries as $query) {
        echo $query . $nl . $nl;
    }

    echo $nl . $nl;
}
#endregion

try {
    $migration->migrate($to); // Execute migration!
    echo 'DONE' . $nl;
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $ex->getMessage() . $nl;
}
```

Now you can:

Run it from console:

`php index.php` - will migrate to lates version

`php index.php 2` - will migrate to version 2 (if current version is bigger - it will migrate down

Run from web browser:

`http://localhost/index.php` and `http://localhost/index.php?to=2` will do the same.

Comment: I crawled through the whole Doctrine migrations bundle, and then I stumbled over your post here on Stack Overflow. Based on that, I came up with a four-lines-of-code solution. I thank you, kind Sir!

Answer (score 5):

In Symfony 6.3 you need something like this...

```
$ symfony console doctrine:migrations:execute DoctrineMigrations\Version20230828161215 --down
```

The FQCN is just the namespace of the migration, normally DoctrineMigrations, followed by the class name which is normally the file name (without extension) of the version.

An example or two in the documentation would have gone a long way.

Comment: works, but needs a double Backslash in my case (linux and docker) `symfony console doctrine:migrations:execute DoctrineMigrations\\Version20230828161215 --down`

i prefer the current-x and current+x method from @Jlblcblu

Answer (score 3):

Symfony 6:

```
bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate current-2
bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate current+5
```

Comment: this works fine since version 6 and should be more on the top

Answer (score 2):

In my case it looks like below:

Reverting changes:

`php bin/console doctrine:migrations:execute "VendorName\ProjectName\Account\Migrations\Version20201002092643" --down`

Processing migration:

`php bin/console doctrine:migrations:execute "VendorName\ProjectName\Account\Migrations\Version20201002092643" --up`

or just

`php bin/console doctrine:migrations:execute "VendorName\ProjectName\Account\Migrations\Version20201002092643"`

and my Symfony configuration for migrations looks as below:

```
doctrine_migrations:
    migrations_paths:
        # namespace is arbitrary but should be different from App\Migrations
        # as migrations classes should NOT be autoloaded
        'DoctrineMigrations': '%kernel.project_dir%/migrations'
        'VendorName\ProjectName\Account\Migrations': '%kernel.project_dir%/component/account/migrations'
```

Comment: Thank you. Starting with 3.0+ you need to write FQCN, not the number. Docs: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-migrations/en/3.0/reference/managing-migrations.html#executing-single-migrations